# How to use cqlshrc in python script?

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra

I have a cluster of (Apache) Cassandra nodes on the GCP and Python3 on one VM.
Using the "cqlsh --cqlshrc" the query that I need can be run without any error.
Inside the cqlshrc there is costume timestamp and increased connection-timeout.

> [copy]
>   DATETIMEFORMAT = %m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S
>
> [connection] 
>   request_timeout = 6000

I Also have the "cqlshrc" file in the "~/.cassandra/" folder so I can use it without passing it as a parameter.
Now the Python script which is using "cassandra-driver" wants to talk to Cassandra and run some queries, but I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "queries.py", line 10, in
>   
>       query1()   File "queries.py", line 6, in query1
>       rows = session.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM freeway_loopdata  WHERE speed > 100 ALLOW FILTERING')   File "cassandra/cluster.py",
>   line 2345, in cassandra.cluster.Session.execute   File
>   "cassandra/cluster.py", line 4304, in
>   cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.result cassandra.ReadFailure: Error
>   from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read]
>   message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures"
>   info={'consistency': 'LOCAL_ONE', 'required_responses': 1,
>   'received_responses': 0, 'failures': 1}

Which is from not increasing the timeout.
How can I pass the "cqlshrc" file inside the Python script as some parameter?

Comment: I have already used "Session.default_timeout=an integer" and "Session.request_timeout=an integer" to increase the timeout and failed.

Comment: how are you declaring the connection to the database? what is the structure of the table? in `cassandra.yaml`, how are you declaring the `listen_address ` value? using an `ALLOW FILTERING` statement is an antipattern.

Comment: also, the way that the Python driver establishes the connection with the database is not related to `cqlshrc`.

Comment: The way I establish the connection is:
`from cassandra.cluster import Cluster`
`cluster = Cluster(['0.0.0.0'],port=9042)`
`session = cluster.connect('cs588damon',wait_for_all_pools=True)`
`session.request_timeout=60000`
`session.execute('USE cs588damon')`

Comment: This piece of code is on the same VM that I can query from.
The same query using **cqlsh** on that VM works just fine.

Comment: Structure of data is completely relational (each column has exactly one value for each row). The reason I have to use no-SQL on this is because of requirement of the school project. Otherwise I would use SQL DB.

Comment: listen_address: 10.168.0.7 (which is the IP of same VM I' running cqlsh and Python code on)
I have 5 VMs on this cluster, so:
seeds: "127.0.0.1,10.168.0.7,10.168.0.5,10.168.0.3,10.168.0.4,10.168.0.6"

Comment: I'm using **ALLOW FILTERING** because the query is on a column that is not a row key. If you want the reason, is that there is NULL value in this column.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout that you're trying to increase is the client side timeout. But if you haven't increased it on the server side (bad idea anyway), then it doesn't help anyway.

Really, you're performing operation that Cassandra isn't optimized for - you're performing aggregation operation (`count`) on the arbitrary field, without restricting the partition key - this lead to situation that Cassandra needs to sift through all data on all nodes, and filter out only needed entries. This is an anti-pattern for Cassandra usage - such kind of queries need to be done via Spark, for example. I recommend to take some courses (DS201 & DS220 at least) on [DataStax Academy](https://academy.datastax.com/) to understand how Cassandra works & how to model data for it.

Comment: The problem is this has to be done with Cassandra and this relational dataset. There is no escape.
I know filtering out couple of rows among all of them is not efficient for this system. But is there any other choice to get the answer on this exact data set with Cassandra? Other than first creating another table base on the original minus the null values then use 'speed' column as primary row.

Comment: This error happens because of the filtering among all the rows of a hug dataset. It takes longer than 10 seconds and fails due lack of any respond within 10 seconds which is the default value for the "connection-timeout".
Are you saying I can not use Python in such condition because there is no option to change the client side config (used by Python)?